# Pan&Zoom with AS3 over a captured image with Cam

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an issue with zooming gesture in iOS over AIR. Here is the code (an excerpt):

```
    package 
    {
        import flash.display.DisplayObject;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.media.Camera;
        import flash.media.Video;
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
        import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
        import flash.display.Shape;
        import flash.display.*;
        import flash.ui.*;

        import flash.media.CameraRoll;
        import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
        import flash.geom.Transform;

        [...]


        private function tiraFoto(e:Event){
            _fotoInit = new BitmapData(capaVideo.width,capaVideo.height);
            _fotoInit.draw(lienzo);
            _captura = new Bitmap(_fotoInit);
            lienzo.addChild(_captura);
            editaFoto();
            _video.attachCamera(null);

        }

        private function editaFoto():void{
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
            lienzo.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, ZoomImage); 
        }

        private function ZoomImage(e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
            lienzo.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
            lienzo.scaleY *= e.scaleY;

        }


  }
}
```

Where, the app, basically captures an image using the iphone's device and then should  scales (zoom), but doesn't... Any suggest?

Thanks in advance,
Dae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flash.display::Bitmap is not an InteractiveObject. Wrap in into Sprite (add as a child to new sprite and add gesture handler for that sprite).